# Are international applicants in UK at disadvantage when applying for PhD in Pure Mathematics?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, funding, united-kingdom

I am a student from Asia and I am applying for PhD in UK universities in pure mathematics for the upcoming season.

I want to know if universities in UK give priority to UK citizens in PhD applications? How disadvantaged are international applicants who are not self funded or funded by their home country?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The admission decision and the funding decision are generally separate in the UK. For admission, there are some sources for mild disadvantages for international applicants (eg admission tutors being less able to judge the quality of an undergraduate degree, letter writers being unfamiliar with their task in a UK context, stuff like that). But these shouldn't be taken as too offputting.

Funding, however, is another story. A primary source of PhD funding in Mathematics in the UK is EPSRC, and they have tight constraints of how much of their PhD funding can be spend on non-residents. Other funding sources such as the Leverhulme Trust may not directly object to funding international PhD students, but instead object to paying the much higher fees most universities charge to foreigners. As such, the competition for the few unrestricted PhD scholarships will be much higher than the one for the "domestic" ones.

There are some scholarship schemes targeted directly at international applicants, such as the Commonwealth scholarships. If you want a chance at funding, you'll need to research these and identify whose criteria you meet. "Blindly" applying to universities directly is unlikely to get you any funding.

Comment: This. Basically only a fraction of funded PhD positions will cover the international tuition fees and are therefore "open to anyone". Consequently, they are much more competitive Sadly.